# HTTP 2 request in python 2.7

Tags: python, http, http2

Is there any difference in making request to HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 in python.

I can make HTTP/1.x calls in python like

```
url = 'http://someURL'
values = {'param1' : 'key',
          'param2' : 'key2'}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
print data
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

Is python supporting making HTTP/2 by default or should I add anything extra.

Comment: I'm *almost sure* it uses HTTP2, and you can check the docs for that. But I think you're better off using the `requests` library. (`pip install requests`). They say that `urllib2` is "thoroughly broken..."

Comment: FYI: https://hyper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's the authors of `requests`.

Comment: @PythonGuy from the docs, I couldn't find that requests supports HTTP/2 also authors of hyper says requests not supports HTTP/2

Comment: @Johnykutty Are you sure? Check again. But you can always do a raw socket send in a TCP packet (yes, you can!) and read the server output using http 2.0.

Comment: You could use [`pycurl`](http://pycurl.io/) but it's verbose and not beginner friendly, especially if you don't know [`libcurl`](https://curl.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments to the question the `requests` library does not support HTTP/2.

From the `requests` library [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

> Requests allows you to send organic, grass-fed **HTTP/1.1** requests, without the need for manual labor.

As of now the only HTTP/2 client for Python I know of is [`hyper`](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which quoting from the docs:

> supports Python 3.4 and Python 2.7.9, and can speak HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1

Comment: hyper is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper#hyper-http2-client-for-python)

Answer (score 9):

For reference, as of 2019, another library supporting HTTP/2 is [HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org).

> HTTPX is a fully featured HTTP client for Python 3, which provides sync and async APIs, and support for both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.

This requires at least Python 3.6. However, at the time of writing in 2020, Python 2 is already EOL, so Python 3.6 should be okay for any users.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hyper` with `requests` module.

```
import requests
from hyper.contrib import HTTP20Adapter
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://http2bin.org', HTTP20Adapter())
r = s.get('https://http2bin.org/get')
print(r.status_code)
```

https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#requests-integration

Comment: hyper is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper#hyper-http2-client-for-python)