# How to fix http.client.UnknownProtocol: HTTP/2.0 error

Tags: python, http, urllib

I'm trying to get some data from a web page in python with urllib, but I get this error: http.client.UnknownProtocol: HTTP/2.0
this is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

# I put this to avoid CORS 
opener = build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
install_opener(opener)

base_page = 'https://stackoverflow.com/example_hypothetical_page'
page = urlopen(base_page)
```

the strange thing is that a few days ago that same code worked ... the only change is that I reinstalled the operating system and installed everything again

Comment: Looks like the `urllib` doesn't support `HTTP/2.0`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570991/http-2-request-in-python-2-7)

Comment: The server shouldn't send a 2.0 response to a 1.1 client.